# Text of TextView is not showing in the Android Studio xml preview panel

Tags: android-studio, textview

When I **do not** hard-code `android:text` of a `TextView`, but refer instead (as is good practice) to `@string/...` the `Android Studio` `xml` preview panel does not show the referenced text (see screenshot below). When running the app, the text is properly displayed in the app, so there seems to be nothing wrong with the referencing or the referenced text.

[Screenshot of preview and xml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UFpV.png)

If I **do** hard-code the text, it is properly displayed in the `xml` preview panel.

What might be wrong?

ADDED: Rendering problem stack (produced after clicking red warning circle in top right corner):

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor392.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:363)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:739)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:895)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 49
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.parseHtml(ResourceHelper.java:546)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getText(BridgeTypedArray.java:216)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1276)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1026)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:108)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:103)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:201)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:121)
    ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, in the upper right-hand corner above the visual layout portion, there is a very small red circle with an exclamation mark in it. That will toggle the issue panel when you click on it.

The fact that it is red indicates that there are issues with this layout (otherwise it would be gray). It will show you the issues that Android Studio is having while rendering your activity and may give you more information on how to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the stack of the rendering problem (red circle). Unfortunately, my lower language knowledge level is insufficient to make any sense of it.

Comment: Okay, so Android Studio is throwing an StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error - that is most likely the cause that it isn't rendering the String value properly - maybe a bug? What does your String value in your strings.xml file?